# Check if tickbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 fields, Checkbox, Textarea and Select list. I am about to hide the textarea and select list when the tickbox is selected then show this two when the tickbox is unchecked.
I have tried this code (below) but have no luck to run this properly. Help please.

```
    var monoG = $('#tickbox');
    var monoM = $('#textarea');
    var monoC = $('#select');

    if ($(monoG).checked = false) {

        $(monoM).hide();
        $(monoC).hide();

    } else {
        $(monoM).show();
        $(monoC).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I've tried all the codes given, all are working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** along with **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** selector

```
if (monoG.is(':checked')
```

or:

```
if (!monoG.prop('checked'))
```

Also `monoG` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it inside `$` again as well as using `change()` event to keep track when your checkbox has been changed:

```
monoG.change(function () {
    if (!monoG.prop('checked')) {
        monoM.hide();
        monoC.hide();   
    } else {
        monoM.show();
        monoC.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [**`.is()`**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [**`:checked`**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector. And please don't wrap the Jquery objects into `$()` again.

Try,

```
  if (monoG.is(":checked")) {
```

Your full code,

```
if (monoG.is(":checked")) {
   monoM.hide();
   monoC.hide();

} else {
    monoM.show();
    monoC.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind using jQuery `change` and then check if the checkbox is checked

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yx99B/)

Answer (score 0):

example with click function

```
$('element').click(function(){
if( $(monoG).is(":checked") ){
   monoM.hide();
   monoC.hide(); 
}else{
    monoM.show();
    monoC.show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The input ferificacion checked, can be performed with the following ways: el = element.
[Test runner "checked"](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/5)

```
$el.prop('checked');
$el.is(':checked');
$el.attr("checked");
$el[0].checked; // is the fastest as Ops/Sec

var monoG = $('#tickbox');
var monoM = $('#textarea');
var monoC = $('#select');

if (!monoG[0].checked) {
    monoM.hide();
    monoC.hide();
} else {
    monoM.show();
    monoC.show();
}
```